# AND command for MIPS Assembly to see if number is divisible by a power of 2?

Tags: assembly, mips

I am trying to use the `AND` command to see if a number is divisible by 4. I do

`and $t0, $t6, 3`  and then compare `$t0` to 0. If the 2 rightmost bits were 0's, everything in `$t0` would then be 0's. However, this isn't seeming to work and I'm unsure why. If anyone could point me the right direction that would be nice.

Comment: That should work. You might need to post more of your code before anyone can help you.

Comment: i actually figured it out. Thank's for the reply though.

Comment: People who happen upon this question in the future aren't really going to be helped by _"I figured it out"_. If you found the solution to your problem yourself you should post it as an answer. If you don't feel it's worth posting because the problem was a typo or something like that you should probably delete your question.

Answer (score 2):

You have to use 'andi' because your comparing a register to an immediate value.

If you were comparing two registers it would be 'and'.

Comment: Some assemblers will accept `and` with a numeric constant, and assemble it to an `andi` machine instruction for you.  But yes, some won't so that's one possible problem the OP might have been having.  Welcome to Stack Overflow. :)